# Java: Stack overflow error - simple recursion

Tags: java, recursion, overflow

This is a simple recursion program I have for a completion problem. I have retuped this on my phone so ignore and syntax errors or missing code.
Is there a specific reason I'm getting stack overflow errors for this specific algorithm?

```
public static int ulam( int x, int c) { 
    if(x==0)
        return 1;
    else if(x%2==0)
        x=x/2;
    else if(x%2==1)
        x=x*2 +1;
    return ulam(x, ++);
}
```

Comment: What is `c`? Function doesn't depend on it. What is it supposed to do? What is `ulam(x, ++)`? Now it is an infinite loop for any odd `x` as `x = x*2 + 1` makes another odd number larger than `x` and so gets back to that option. I assume you wanted `x = x/2 + 1`.

Comment: Entering this on your phone or not doesn't matter. Fix any typos in the code you posted. We can't help you very well if the code you posted has typos. Please fix. It isn't valid code at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion goes too deep. Everytime you enter the function recursively it puts the parameters and the return value on the stack.

If you recurse too often, the stack overflows.

Heres what your function does for x == 7

```
x = 15
x = 30
x = 15
x = 30
```

... it will run infinitely and therefore overflow the stack

Comment: What do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0):

The following is not a valid Java syntax.

return ulam(x, ++);

Perhaps, as others have suggested, you'd like to fix that.